# Async function returns pending promise node js

Tags: node.js

This is a very easy question but no google search results return the correct answer.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const poolec2 = require("./db");
require("./function")();

returnMappings = async function(connection){
  try {
    let mapping = await connection.query("SELECT ticker FROM mappings");
    let results = await mapping.rows;
    //console.log(results);
    return results;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};

const mappings = returnMappings(poolec2);
console.log(mappings);
```

What am I missing here that is not returning my data? When I unquote `console.log(results);` I can see the desired results in my terminal. I've tried various versions of using .then but have not had any success `return results.then;`, `const mappings = returnMappings(poolec2).then;`, `console.log(mappings.then);`. I've also tried returning my results outside of my try catch with no luck. I'm really stuck trying to understand how I go about returning a from an async function.

**EDIT**

The goal is to pass the results from the above async function to another function to check if the a user inputted value exists in that vector of mappings. So indexOf based on a user input, I then use if else to return true or false. With the final results being either true or false.

```
checkMappings = function(string,input){
  stringArray = string;
  value = stringArray.indexOf(input);
  if(value > -1){
      return false
  }else{
      return true
  }
};
```

**SOLUTION**

```
returnMappings = async function(connection,input){
  try {
    const mapping = await connection.query("SELECT ticker FROM mappings_production");
    const results = await mapping.rows;
    //console.log(results);
    return results;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};

checkMappings = function(string,input){
  let stringArray = JSON.stringify(string);
  let value = stringArrayC1.indexOf(input);
  function test(a) {
    let check;
    if(a > -1) {
      return true
    }else {
      return false
    }
  };
  console.log(test(value));
  return test(value);
};

const resMappingCheck = returnMappings(poolec2).then((mappings) => checkMappings(mappings,"AAPL"));

console.log(resMappingCheck);
```

this worked for what I needed to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `await` can only be used in an async function, but using `.then()` is functionally equivalent.

This syntax that should work for you:

`returnMappings(poolec2).then((mappings) => console.log(mappings));`

if you want to do something more elaborate / multi-line, you can use curly braces like so:

```
returnMappings(poolec2).then((mappings) => {
  console.log(mappings)
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to chain two functions together, then you'll need to start with the `.then()` pattern: you can declare the callback function in `.then()` to be asynchronous. At that point, you can start to use `await` like you're used to.

I'm not sure what relationship you're trying to create between `returnMappings()` and `checkMappings()`, but you can chain them together like this: *(note the use of `async` on the first line to allow the use of `await` inside the callback.)*

```
returnMappings('test').then(async (mapping) => {
  const checkResult = await checkMappings(mapping)
  console.log(`checkMapping result: ${checkResult}`)
}).catch((err) => console.log(`Error: ${err}`))
```

Comment: I've tried this and I'm given the error message ```await is only valid in async function```

Comment: @S3AN556 As the error message says, you can only use `await` in an async function.

Comment: Your first line of code does log the correct data. How can I store that data to be used in another function? Or do I need to do all of this in the same function, I've added more context above.

Comment: @S3AN556 I've updated my answer to elaborate; let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`const mappings = await returnMappings(poolec2);`

That will work if you wrap the code inside an async function. Or you could do:

```
let mappings;
returnMappings(poolec2).then(res => {
    mappings = res;
});
```

Comment: I think I'm understanding some of what you and others are saying, I need to call returnMappings within an async function...just as my error message tells me to. See my attempt at a solution above, I've added an additional explanation.

Comment: You got it. Do what your error messages tell you to ;)